# idTCPServer sending message to idTCPClient without client activity

Tags: c++, c++builder, indy

I'm using Embarcadero C++ Builder and I know how to open a connection and wait for an answer from the server side (client can open connection, send message and read message that was sent from server until connection close).

Client side:

```cpp
IdTCPClient1->Connect();
IdTCPClient1->Socket->WriteLn("message from client");
ShowMessage(IdTCPClient1->Socket->ReadLn());
IdTCPClient1->Disconnect();
```

Server side:

```cpp
ShowMessage(AContext->Connection->Socket->ReadLn());    
AContext->Connection->Socket->WriteLn("Message from server");
AContext->Connection->Disconnect();
```

Now exchange of messages is possible if client opens the connection on the client side, but I need server to send message to all users, which means that clients will not know when to open the connection. I guess I'm looking for some event that waits for a server message. All examples I have found are in Delphi and not C++. Also, when each client connects for the first time I made a `vector<TIdContext*>` to save all of the connections, which works fine.

Comment: If you're not connected then you can't send a message. Why not connect, and then *leave the connection open* so both sides can send messages, instead of disconnecting straight away?

Comment: @immibis, why? Of course you can send a message on unconnected socket. Just not TCP message.

Comment: Looks like TCP is not the best transport for you. Probably you'd be better of with UDP.

Comment: @SergeyA TCP is perfectly reasonable here.

Comment: @immibis, since when sending the same message to multiple clients over unicast is reasonable?

Comment: @SergeyA You know that multicast doesn't work over the Internet, right?

Comment: @immibis, it doesn't work over carrier pidgeons either. Question is not saying anything about Internet nor pidgeons.

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable to want to send a duplicate message to multiple users at the same time. Consider at chat room, for instance. When a user enters or leaves the room, other users need to be told as much. This is not an uncommon requirement for TCP servers with multiple clients.

Comment: Just because most Indy examples are written in Delphi does not mean they can't be used in C++Builder.  Indy is the same in both environments, just translate the code from one language to the other, it is not that hard.  The interfaces, properties, and method calls are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to send a message from TIdTCPServer to all the connected clients:

```
TIdContext *MyContext;
TList *ClientsList = IdTCPServer1->Contexts->LockList();
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < ClientsList->Count; i++) {
        MyContext = (TIdContext*) ClientsList->Items[i];
        MyContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn("Message for all the clients");
    }
__finally {
    IdTCPServer1->Contexts->UnlockList();
}
```

Comment: Where on client should I read message from server? Is it some built-in event? When I know that server will send message I just wait for message but when server is sending message without client request I don't really know what to do then.

Comment: This is a *very* bare-bones example. It does not take protocol into account. What if a client were in the middle of sending a command, or the server were in the middle of sending a response? The `WriteLn()` would trample on any response data being sent. TIdTCPServer is a multi-threaded component, each client runs in its own thread, and each thread handles the socket I/O for its respective client. Using `LockList()` does not make the code thread-safe in general...

Comment: When the server needs to send *unsolicited* messages to a client, you should create a thread-safe message queue (in this case, `TIdThreadSafeStringList` will work) in the `OnConnect` event and free it in the `OnDisconnect` event, then the above loop (in any thread) can put new messages into the queue of each client and let the `OnExecute` event handler send the contents of the queue when it is actually safe to do so, when it is not busy doing something else. I have posted *many* examples of that model before, here on StackOverflow, on the Embarcadero forums, and the Indy forums. Search around.

Comment: On the client side, when dealing with *unsolicited* messages, the client must *continuously* monitor the connection for new inbound messages, either in a timer or better in a worker thread. There is no client-side event for this. Which also means you have to do *ALL* of your reading in that timer/thread, including responses to commands sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I ended up using thread and it works just like I wanted. Also Thanks to other people for ideas and suggestions. It actually impressed me how quick I got valuable answers here. So i guess admin can put lock on this or whatever the procedure is. And yea thanks again guys.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You said

> ...which means that clients will not know when to open the connection. I guess I'm looking for some event that waits for a server message.

There are very good options in the answer above, if you want to stay with the single TCP connection, leaving it open, and monitoring for messages.

Another option that was mentioned in a comment was to (also) set up a UDP connection.  On each of your "clients", create an iDUDPServer that listens on a specific port (will be different port than your TCP connection).  On your "Server", create a TIdUDPClient.  **Note the difference in terminology here, you will install the UDPServer on what you call your TCP client and vice versa**.

Send a UDP message to your "Client"s from the server using this. You will catch the message in the (Client's) IdUDPServer OnUDPRead event.

If all of your clients are on the same network segment you can use a UDP broadcast to send a single message to all clients listening.  If not, send messages to each of your clients using their IP address.

One of your issues was the lack  of C++ examples.  Sorry, I can't help with C++ code.  Here is pseudocode/procedure, you'll have to manage language syntax:

*On your "Client",*

1. create an TIdUDPServer (put it on a form, it has to be available to listen).
2. Set the DefaultPort to the listening port (set other options if you like)
3. Assign event code for IdUDPServerUDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
   AData: TArray; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle).  The incoming data is in AData.  You can confirm the IP of the source by looking at ABinding.PeerIP, if you care.

On your "Server"

1. create TIdUPDClient.
2. send your  message either to a specific  IP by:

   a: Set IdUDPClient.Host  (target)

   b: Set IdUDPClient.Port  (target)

   c:  IdUDPClient.Send(msg)

   OR, you can broadcast to all on your network segment with:

   a: IdUDPClient.Broadcast(msg,TargetPort)
3. The "msg" will be presented on your Clients in the IdUDPServerUDPRead event as the AData parameter.

This option can be slightly more complex because two message paths are involved, but it does not require that the TCP connections to your server be opened by the clients nor does it involve setting up a monitor loop for inbound messages.  In fact, it can be used to advertise the location of your server if the clients don't know were to connect.  This UDP communication is *in addition* to your existing TCP connection, so those connections remain unchanged.